# Luajava: change java public static variable value in lua

Tags: java, lua, luajava

I have following java code.

```
public class Settings {

    public static float delay= 3f; // in seconds


}
```

And following lua code

```
local a = luajava.bindClass("Settings");
print (a.delay) -- works normally
-- a.delay = 5; -- this will cause "attempt to index local "a"
```

I can't set new value to the public static variable "delay". Can I override java public static variable in lua?

Comment: static members are inherited, but you can't override them

Comment: My mistake. Should be overwrite, not override. Already modify the title to "change" accordingly.<br>
As you can see from the code.

Comment: members of variables are always to be considered 'final', so no, you won't be able to overwrite them either.

Comment: Thanks. Stultuske. Please write it as an answer. Then I can choose it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in interfaces are always implicitly final, which is why they can't be overwritten.